# global uninstall angular cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Hi I've tried to uninstall global @angular/cli but I still can use ng -v and it reports warning: Your global Angular CLI version (1.7.0) is greater than your local

I tried:

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache verify
```

But ng -v still report the warning that my global is greater than local. Please help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is this actually causing an issue, or is it just annoying you a bit?

Comment: just annoying. I don't want to set global warning version off since I know when creating new component, it will use the global cmd

Answer (score 3):

**Using following commands to uninstall :**

**1. Run the following command in your terminal to uninstall the angular cli (global) package.**

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
```

**2. Clear the cache**

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Note: In macOS, you need to add sudo before the npm command.
Example for mac users:

```
sudo npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
```

If you are using an old version of angular-cli then you can uninstall it like this.

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
```

You can also install the latest version of angular cli by using the following command.

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

for mac:

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the Following steps to uninstall angular cli completely

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli // Use sudo before to give administrator permission
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli // Use sudo before to give administrator permission
```

`npm cache clean` or `npm cache clean --force`

To reinstall the latest version try this

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Answer (score -2):

Use this command to uninstall the angular-cli ,it will update the dependencies and also do try to clear the cache once.

```
npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli
```

Comment: The user is trying to uninstall the Global install of angular.  Your command did not affect the global install and only uninstalled the local instance.